# MacBook Pro-Change Background doesn't display/use all of the jpg pictures in the folder

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a new MacBook Pro.   I just downloaded several free HD backgrounds (about 50+)from the internet and placed in a folder.   I added the folder to the Desktop & Screen Saver app.

All of the new images are .jpg files.    But when I added the folder, only 10 of the images display and are used as the background.

I researched online and tried setting "Change picture" to every 5 seconds to try and "force" cycling through all of the pictures -- this didn't work.

I looked at file details --- thee only difference is the date of the files.   The folder is only displaying files I added over a month ago. (Also downloaded from the web, same websites.)

I am not using iCloud Drive (I use Google for backup.)

Any ideas??

Comment: Have you been able to open all these image files in Preview?

Comment: Yes with no issues.   I even tried saving as .jpeg copy --- still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

OK - I figured it out.     You have to click the FOLDER under its root when you add it to the Desktop & Screen Saver folder with "+"

For example.....if the folder is ....Documents\Backgrounds\winter(jpg files) --- you have to select the folder under ....\Documents\Backgrounds (select Winter)

I selected it under the actual directory ...\Documents\Backgrounds\Winter all of the jpg files displaying and selected "Winter" at the top.   (Need to select one directory back)